# Order by (oracle) don't work

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by

I have select statement, i need to add order by mb.id

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT (anything)
                        resxml
                FROM PF_M_CNTR_BATCH mb
                     INNER JOIN PF_CNTR_BATCH b ON mb.batch_id = b.batch_id
                     INNER JOIN PF_CONTRACT ct
                        ON mb.CONTRACT_ID = ct.CONTRACT_ID
                     INNER JOIN PF_CLIENT cl
                        ON ct.CLIENT_ID_UCH = cl.CLIENT_ID
                     INNER JOIN PF_FCLIENT fcl
                        ON cl.FCLIENT_ID = fcl.FCLIENT_ID
               WHERE b.batch_id = v_batch_id) t;
```

I try, but have error

> PLS-00905:  NPF.SP_CNTR_BATCH_GET_XML
>   ORA-06550:

```
 FROM PF_M_CNTR_BATCH mb
                         INNER JOIN PF_CNTR_BATCH b ON mb.batch_id = b.batch_id
                         INNER JOIN PF_CONTRACT ct
                            ON mb.CONTRACT_ID = ct.CONTRACT_ID
                         INNER JOIN PF_CLIENT cl
                            ON ct.CLIENT_ID_UCH = cl.CLIENT_ID
                         INNER JOIN PF_FCLIENT fcl
                            ON cl.FCLIENT_ID = fcl.FCLIENT_ID
                   WHERE b.batch_id = v_batch_id ORDER BY mb.ID) t;
```

Answer (score 2):

That exception comes with additional information about the error.  Without it, we can only guess.  However, I can guess that the right-parenthesis and the `t` on the last line are both wrong.